# how to customize and organise Layouts Folder(Size) properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tested  my app in some devices with different sizes, and i've got terrible   style at last. i've read some documents about folder layout and sizes for customizing layouts for different sizes of phone.

So base on what i've read i've added below lines into Manifest.

```
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens= "true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
```

and copied layout contents to other created folders which they are :

```
layout-large
layout-small
layout-xlarge
layout-xlarge-land
```

and started to edit one of them to see the result, and nothing happend and design was same, so i thought i could be designed wrong xml folder, so base on another tutorial i've added another folder with `layout-sw320dp` and it's worked but problem is now, everything is showing like 320dp folder, large and small doesn't matter. and in design view all folders are phones models sizes changed to :

```
Nexus One -> sw320dp\*.xml
Pixel -> sw320dp\*.xml
```

So what's the reason of this? and what are the sizes of these layout folders with `small` and `large` name exactly? and how i should make this layout work properly?

Looks like my folders are not actually related to exact sizes, 320 is overwriting on all sizes except wear android.

Comment: You don't need those support lines.  The default it true.  YOu only add them if its false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swXXXdp` resource modifier means that this folder will be selected if the device's "smallest width" is `XXX` dp **or greater**. So if you have these two directories:

```
res/layout/
res/layout-sw320dp/
```

Then any device that has a smallest width of 319dp or less will use the `layout/` files, and any device that has a smallest width of 320dp or more will use the `layout-sw320dp/` files. Almost every device is 320dp or more, so you'll see that almost every device uses this folder.

Modern phones tend to have around 400dp of smallest width. You can always look screen specs up online. For example, https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_2-8733.php says that the Pixel 2 is 1080px wide at 441 pixels per inch; this works out to 391dp (1080 / (441/160)).

Common cutoffs for the `swXXXdp` modifiers are 600dp for seven-inch tablets and 720dp for ten-inch tablets. So you might want a project structure like this:

```
res/layout/            <-- everything smaller than a 7" tablet
res/layout-sw600dp/    <-- 7" tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/    <-- 10" tablets
```

Note, though, that you can use any number you want. `sw503dp` is totally valid. You'll just have to choose what numbers work well for your layouts.

As for `layout-large` and `layout-small` etc, just ignore those. Those are outdated, and were used before the `swXXXdp` qualifier was added. Unless you're developing for extremely old API versions, you're better off just using `swXXXdp` instead.

Comment: So base of what u said it's better to don't focus on outdated, and focus on those 3 methods. i'm actually developing for api 19 and after all i've got some issues with some real device, what u think about constraintLayout? and do you think messing around with constraintLayout fix my problem? looks like these days, responsive problems are fixing with using constraintLayout.

Comment: And also i used `gsmarena` to get specs but i thought i should set swXXXdp base on resolution like `320x480=>sw320dp or 420x580=>sw420dp` so u mean even if i wanted to work on them i should work on (ppi density) but how to calculate exact parameter for this? should i use `sw441dp` or not?

Comment: Android uses "density-independent" units (dp); there are 160 dp per physical inch. So when you see that a display has 441 pixels per inch, you can divide that number by 160 to see how many pixels make up one dp. For 441/160, it's about 2.75 pixels per dp. With that, you know that a 1080 _pixel_ wide screen will be about 390 _dp_ wide. So, short answer, screen resolution isn't what matters, it's screen resolution _and_ pixel density.

Comment: Thanks for response and great explain.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting the `layout` name with capital letter `Layout-large`. Replace those letters with small case (e.g: `layout-...`) and it would work.

Comment: i'm sorry my friend i started with capital here, in original project is with small, i'll fix them here asap. Sorry.

Comment: app is only listening to 320dp folder, i'm using a emulator with 900x1440 and it's only listening to 320dp's layout folder.

Comment: You guys don't need to downvote my answer. I was responded to initial post before he modified it. The above comment can prove that.

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't downvote. i've upvote it if it's help my friend and thanks for response.